# How to show nested level data in table view structure

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have to show nested level table in tree structure. the level may be 5 or 6 times nested.
Please suggest me how I will achieve this.

Comment: Don't.. 5-6 nested levels are way too much to be user-friendly. consider other patterns, like `UINavigationController`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are looking for but you can try to find an open source component that can do this for you.

You can find such components by using this website for example:
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=tableview